# Redirect the webservice call to http://[remote server ip]:7777 to http://[local machine ip]:8888

Tags: linux, iptables, ssh-tunnel

I have a webservice running on a remote machine available to me through ssh tunneling.  Therefore I will be able to access the webservice through `http://[local machine ip]:8888`. But the problem here is, My source code trying to access the webservice through the public ip (`http://[remote server ip]:7777`). So I need all the traffic originated from my local machine to the remote machine should be redirected to `http://[local machine ip]:8888`.

For eg `http://[remote server ip]:7777` Redirected to `http://[local machine ip]:8888`

Please note: the ports are different and my OS is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d [remote server ip] --dport 7777 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination [local machine ip]:8888
```